# Displaying word frequencies of 0 in an ArrayList

Tags: java, hashmap, frequency

i'm looking for some assistance. I've made a program that uses two classes - that i've also made. The first class is called CollectionOfWords that reads in text-files and store the words contained in the text-files within a HashMap. The second is called WordFrequencies that calls an object called Collection from the CollectionOfWords class, which in turn reads in another document and to see if the documents contents are in the Collection. This then outputs an ArrayList with the frequencies counted in the document.

Whilst this works and returns the frequencies of the words found in both the collection and document, i'd like it to be able to produce zero values for the words that are in the collection, but not in the document, if that makes sense? For example, test3 returns [1, 1, 1], but i'd like it to return [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1] - where the zeroes represent the words in the collection, but are not found in test3.

The test text-files i use can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B1cDpjmZZo01HizxJUSWSVIlHcQke2mU

Cheers

WordFrequencies

```
public class WordFrequencies {

static HashMap<String, Integer> collection = new HashMap<>();

private static ArrayList<Integer> processDocument(String inFileName) throws IOException {

        // Rests collections frequency values to zero
        collection.clear();

        // Reads in the new document file to an ArrayList
        Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(inFileName));
        ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(textFile.hasNext()) {
            file.add(textFile.next().trim().toLowerCase());
        }

        /* Iterates the ArrayList of words -and- updates collection with 
           frequency of words in the document */
        for(String word : file) {
            Integer dict = collection.get(word);
            if (!collection.containsKey(word)) {
                collection.put(word, 1); 
            } else {
                collection.put(word, dict + 1);
            }
        }

        textFile.close();

        // Stores the frequency values in an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(collection.values());
        return values;  
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Stores text files for the dictionary (collection of words)
        List<String> textFileList = Arrays.asList("Test.txt", "Test2.txt");

        // Declares empty ArrayLists for output of processDocument function 
        ArrayList<Integer> test3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> test4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Creates a new CollectionOfWords object called dictionary 
        CollectionOfWords dictionary = new CollectionOfWords(collection);

        // Reads in the ArrayLists text files and processes it
        for (String text : textFileList) {
            dictionary.scanFile(text);
        }

        try {

            test3 = processDocument("test3.txt");
            test4 = processDocument("test4.txt");

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      

        System.out.println(test3);
        System.out.println(test4);
    }
}
```

CollectionOfWords

```
public class CollectionOfWords {
    // Declare set in a higher scope (making it a property within the object)
    private HashMap<String, Integer> collection = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    // Assigns the value of the parameter to the field of the same name
    public CollectionOfWords(HashMap<String, Integer> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    // Gets input text file, removes white spaces and adds to dictionary object
    public void scanFile(String textFileName) {
        try {

            Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(textFileName));

            while (textFile.hasNext()) {
                 collection.put(textFile.next().trim(), 0);
            }

            textFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printDict(HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary) {
        System.out.println(dictionary.keySet());
    }    
}
```

Comment: We are not a *"Let's give us your requirements and we do all the work for you for nothing in return"*-service

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni Hum... After reading carefully your code I don't get how both classes are related. Seems to me as if they are independent. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @LittleSanti WordFrequencies calls a function called 'scanFile' from CollectionOfWords, after creating a new CollectionOfWords object that works with the function, if that makes sense

Comment: @Lino A link to google drive folder with the test files i've been using has been provided

Comment: @LittleSanti It's granted that i could probably combine all of this into one class, but this isn't for anything other than personal use outside of my 9 - 5 that isn't related to programming. The way i've structured everything helps me understand how things work.

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni Although this is not part of your question, passing the HashMap through the contructor is not really done a lot. A better way would be to use a static function with the map as an argument. This is in part why some people were confused.

Comment: @ThijsSteel Cheers man. I'll keep that in mind once i tidy everything up. I want to get the project fully finished first. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't go through the trouble of figuring out your entire code, so sorry if this answer is stupid.

As a solution to your problem, you could initialize the map with every word in the dictionary mapping to zero. Right now, you use the `clear` method on the hashmap, this does not set everything to zero, but removes all the mappings.

The following code should work, use it instead of `collection.clear()`

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : collection.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(0);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that. I had no idea that the clear() function for HashMaps removes all mappings. Thanks for that.